# Socket hang up error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Since upgrading to Ember 1.13.2 and Ember Data 1.13.4. I've been receiving the following error once in a while. This only happens when I manually refresh the page.

What could be causing this?

```
Error proxying to http://localhost:3099/
socket hang up
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:215:15)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:247:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at TCP.close (net.js:485:12)
```

Comment: I can reproduce the problem when I shut down webrick but isn't that expected?

Comment: I haven't shut down the proxy server (in this case unicorn).

Comment: Do you have to restart the server when this happens?

Comment: No, I just refresh again, and it starts working again. And then the error happens again after a few minutes.